# Significato di "pelle salsa"

Tags: word-meaning, adjectives

Nel libro *Cronaca familiare*, di Vasco Pratolini, ho letto:

> Dapprima egli mi chiese notizie della mia vita, e di fronte al mio divagare sorrideva, mostrava i suoi denti opachi, il suo volto colore avorio; una **pelle salsa** consumata dal tempo.

Ho cercato il significato di "salso" in alcuni dizionari e ho visto che può significare "che contiene sale, che ha sapore o odore salato" oppure, in senso figurato, "mordace, pungente". Tuttavia, non capisco il senso dell'espressione "pelle salsa" nella frase sopra citata. Sapreste spiegarmelo?

Comment: Secondo me potrebbe provenire dal latino "salsus" che significa salato. Una pelle invecchiata, consumata

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sicuramente qui per "salsa" si intende proprio "salata" o, meglio, consumata, inaridita e screpolata come dall'effetto della salsedine.